# Can you prove that electricity was generated by a photovoltaic cell?

Tags: current-measurement, solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller, power-meter

I am wondering if it would be possible to build a photovoltaic cell that kept track of the electricity it generated (perhaps with a built-in meter), such that you could not trick the meter without destroying it.

The idea would be to make cheating the meter (by pumping electricity from a different source through it) pretty much impossible.

Does anything similar in a different context (maybe electric meters on the sides of houses) already exist?

EDIT: Sorry for posting an XY question — that wasn’t intentional. But I did not see the value of stating the underlying motive, which is something along the lines of what was pointed out in the comments. I have the idea that in certain contexts where owners of PV cells get paid for the electricity they generate, they could get electricity cheaper somewhere else and fool the wattmeter. My  question was meant to be simple and general. Since I know very little about EE I thought something like this might already exist or be known to be impossible.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: You propose the use of a wattmeter -- what keeps me from taking a drill and carefully drilling through the PV cell to attach my own wires directly to the wiring intrinsic to the cells? Is there a reason why this cannot be addressed simply by inspection/regulatory processes?

Comment: "I am wondering if it would be possible to build ....."  - probably yes (depending on how much effort you're willing to put into the anti-trickery mechanism). But this really reads as a stereotypical XY question. What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: To jump to the defense of someone posting an XY problem (which I rarely do): In many countries, there's subsidies for electricity produced by renewable sources on private infrastructure, sometimes these even exceed the spot price of electricity delivered to your neighbor, opening some doors to fraud.

Comment: @MarcusMuller My colleague has a separate meter for his PV panels for selling green electricity certificates (the company upstream package them from clients like him) whereas the grid company don’t care where the energy comes from and only measure on the AC side.

Comment: I know at least one, that was doing this kind of "business" - Buys electricity from grid and then resells back to the grid, but for higher price as it is eco solar.  I do think that this is solved by simply paying only the extra produced power- if you consume the same amount to what you produce, you get nothing. So no special metering is needed.

Comment: Basically you want a tamper-evident thingy. There's lots of applications with the same problem, e.g. measuring miles traveled on a truck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no "colour" to electricity which you could use. You *could* put a tamper-evident light meter next to the panels to determine if the value on the meter is plausible or not, though.